# Slow performance with jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Can anyone see why this would be performing so slow?
If there is a not an obvious problem, I can eliminate the jQuery as the problem and turn my attention to my CSS.

```
       $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-content1',
            show:{
                effect:"blind",
                duration:500
            },
            buttons: {
                "discharge": {
                    text: " Discharge ",
                    click: function () {
                        $('#DisRefForm').submit(); 
                    },
                    class: 'btn purple',
                    style: 'font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'
                },
                "cancel": {
                    text: " Cancel",
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                    class: 'btn blue', 
                    style: 'font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'
                }
            },

    });
```

DisRefForm is the ID of my form..
The jQuery function linked back to a div...

```
     <div id="dialog-modal" title="Discharge Warning">
        <p>Are you sure you want to discharge this Guy ?</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: How slow is it? It's not the 500 milliseconds show effect, is it?

Comment: what's performing slow ? buttons click events triggering ? dialog showing ? (for last try smaller duration)

Comment: NO, it display's fine , however when I place the mouse over the btn's the cursor takes a some time to change to the hand icon and once the btn is clicked there is a further delay... there is a lot of CSS involved, but I just want to be sure it's not the jQuery itself...

Comment: Using developer tools, the following is shown                    Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Comment: ok I commented out the modal:true line and it's fire as fast I would have expected.... will taking out that line have any knock on effect??

Comment: well the line "modal:true" will calculate the highest z-index and window width and height, maybe thats too much calculation on your site

Comment: thanks john, that would make sense there is alot going on...

Answer (score 0):

Removed modal:true for jQuery. Speed's it right up !